# Understand how to integrate STM32F407VG MCU on custom PCB and program it

Tags: pcb, stm32, firmware, st-link

I have been messing around with the STMF407VG for a few weeks now using a discovery board. Been the steep learning curve but I think I have made significant progress on learning firmware development with it. I have gotten my code to be to a point where I wanted to have a custom PCB solution. I went ahead and looked at a few implementations of other STM32 dev boards and used that to help understand how to connect everything up.

I finally got my boards in the mail. Power seems to be okay to the target, I measured the power rails for all of the pins and looks okay. Both boot pins are grounded, and the reset line is held high. Though when I try to upload a blank project to my custom PCB, I get the error that there is "No device found on target". Only thing I can think of is that I must have miswired the port that connects to the ST LINK V2 I purchased. I never made a custom PCB with an ARM MCU before so this is my first go at it. I have attached a picture of the MCU section of the schematic. Is there perhaps some green horn mistake I made?

Any hints are welcome!

[image: MCU Page]

Comment: for me boot0 and boot1 are high, no? Should remove R33 and R44

Comment: I suggest reading the datasheet and hardware design getting started application notes. There are some things that are not entirely wrong but not entirely right either. Vbat is floating and there is a pull-up on nRST. Most likely VCap pins should both be connected together too. There is also no bulk capacitor that is larger than 100nF at the MCU. Are you sure the VUSB can be directly connected to PA9? Maybe add a UART header so that JTAG is not absolutely necessary when debugging. Depends on how you intend to program it but make sure that this pinmap does not conflict with bootloader pins.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Pretty much what I have is copy pasta from the dev board buy yeah I can see them going against certain design rules as well. So actually, my circuit does work! I was a dum dum and didn't plug my header in all the way. So if anyone wants to use this as a reference, it has been tested to be good. Thanks for answering everyone!